# (Flutter): How to catch the drag event with a DraggableScrollableSheet

Tags: android, flutter

[Image of the App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMWBJ.gif)

Hi, I'm trying to resize a widget (GoogleMap) while a DraggableScrollableSheet is being drag. The two Widgets are in a Stack. so far i have been able to catch the dragging action only at the beggining and at the end of the dragging action with GestureDetector (onVerticalDragStart, onVerticalDragDown, onPanDown). I can also get the size and the position of the DraggableScrollableSheet with a GlobalKey  (_globalKeyResultatRech).
Is there a way i can **continiously** get the dragging event then i'll setState (change the GoogleMap height) and rebuild the view while dragging ?

Thanks.

Here is the code (simplified):

```
           Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: //variable size to add later
                child: GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: _initialCamera,
                  mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    controller.setMapStyle(
                    //map style
                    _mapController.complete(controller);
                    
                  },
                  onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
                  markers: _markers,
                  polylines: _polylines,
                  circles: Set.of((circle != null) ? [circle] : []),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox.expand(
                child: GestureDetector(
                        onPanDown: (panDowndetails) => {
                        print('onPanDown called')
                        },
                        onVerticalDragStart: (verticalDragStartdetails) => {
                        print('onVerticalDragStart called')
                        },
                        onVerticalDragDown: (VerticalDragDowndetails) {
                        print('onVerticalDragDown called');
                          },
                        child: SizedBox.expand(
                            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                                initialChildSize: 0.3,
                                minChildSize: 0.1,
                                maxChildSize: 0.5,
                                builder: (BuildContext c, s) {
                                  return Container(
                                      key: _globalKeyResultatRech,
                                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                          controller: s,
                                          child: ListView(
                                            controller: s,
                                            shrinkWrap: true,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              // Items 
                                            ],
                                          )));
                                })),
                      )
              ),
              // Positionned Item 1 (TextFiels)
              // Positionned Item 2 (Focus Button)
              // Positionned Item 3 (GPS Button)
            ],
          ), 
        ),
```

**EDIT:**
Never mind. GestureDetector was useless in my case. I find a built in Flutter class `NotificationListener` which takes as parameter `<DraggableScrollableNotification>`.  Here the code for those who are interrested:

(Code simplified)

```
Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: //variable height to add later
                child: GoogleMap(
                  initialCameraPosition: _initialCamera,
                  mapToolbarEnabled: false,
                  onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                    controller.setMapStyle(
                    //map style
                    _mapController.complete(controller);
                    
                  },
                  onCameraMove: _onCameraMove,
                  markers: _markers,
                  polylines: _polylines,
                  circles: Set.of((circle != null) ? [circle] : []),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox.expand(
                child: NotificationListener<DraggableScrollableNotification>(

                      onNotification: (notification){
                        //TODO
                        setState(() {
                          
                        });
                        return true;
                      },
                        child: SizedBox.expand(
                            child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
                                initialChildSize: 0.3,
                                minChildSize: 0.1,
                                maxChildSize: 0.5,
                                builder: (BuildContext c, s) {
                                  return Container(
                                      key: _globalKeyResultatRech,
                                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                          controller: s,
                                          child: ListView(
                                            controller: s,
                                            shrinkWrap: true,
                                            children: <Widget>[
                                              // Items 
                                            ],
                                          )));
                                })),
                      )
              ),
              // Positionned Item 1 (TextFiels)
              // Positionned Item 2 (Focus Button)
              // Positionned Item 3 (GPS Button)
            ],
          ), 
        ),
```

Comment: GestureDetector has `onVerticalDragUpdate`.

Comment: did you find any solution to this problem??